# How is output current of a MOSFET gate driver controlled?

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, opto-isolator, mosfet-driver, gate-driving

I have been studying a lot about gate drivers, and I understand the calculation of the current requirement, but what I don't understand is how the output current of the driver IC is regulated.

Specifically, I have a [TLP5772H](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/ap-en/semiconductor/product/optoelectronics/detail.TLP5772H.html) as a gate driver and my MOSFET is an [IPU60R2K1CEAKMA1](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IPU60R2K1CE-DS-v02_02-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46249be182c0149c7e409461eac).

The driver's datasheet specifies the minimum output current but not the maximum.

[image]

How is the current controlled? From what I read about the gate resistor Rg it only helps in suppressing transients and has no impact on drive current.

Please correct me if I am wrong here and let me know which parameter is used to control this current (in context of MOSFET based photocoupler gate drivers).

Comment: Just a note, it is always a good idea to put a low-value gate resistor on the board.  Fast switching tends to create EMI, and later on if the device is to pass EMC tests, that value (and resulting switching speed) may have to be slowed slightly by increasing the value.  Side-note, for repeated high current pulses, tiny metal film resistors are prone to failure.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't listen to the datasheets when they list max or minimum currents for gate drivers. They usually test these things in unrealistic scenarios. Furthermore, gate drivers do not necessarily control their output current. It is a function of your circuit, especially the FET you are driving.

Anyway, it helps to understand why we need a large current for a gate driver.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flveNl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A FET has parasitic capacitances from gate to source, gate to drain and drain to source (ignore the values in the schematic, they are absurdly high). These are listed in the datasheets, but you may have to do some deciphering from Coss, Ciss, and Crss. The FET package itself also has some resistance (and inductance). Even the FETs within the gate driver IC have a resistance. When a gate driver "turns on" you are essentially charging this gate to source cap from your gate driver VCC through the gate driver top FET resistance, the gate resistor on your board and the internal gate resistance of the FET. That is what controls the current. 12 V is divided by a few ohms or so. You will then have to charge the gate to drain cap (look up Miller Plateau) but we can ignore that for now.

As an example, a gate driver top FET may have an R<sub>ds(on)</sub> of 1.3 Ω followed by the gate drive resistor of 4.7 Ω, and an internal resistance in the driven FET of another 1 Ω. This gives us a grand total of 7 Ω. Now it is simply a matter of charging the GS cap (usually in the order of a few thousand pF) through a 7 Ω resistor. Since a cap is essentially a short circuit when empty, the initial peak current would be 12 V (or whatever your gate driver VCC is) divided by 7 Ω, or less than 2 A.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> *what I don't understand is how the output current of the driver IC
> regulated*

Basically it isn't and you need to use an output resistor (\$R_G\$) if driving the gate of a MOSFET. Let's look at the recommended operating condition table: -

[image]

So, what this table tells you is where you should be operating the device and, if you are driving +12 volts onto the gate-source of a MOSFET then, due to gate-source capacitance, the peak current needs to be limited by a resistor to keep within the 2.5 amps specified. These are recommended operating ranges AND they are the same values as the absolute maximum ratings so, my advice is don't allow the peak current to rise higher than about two-thirds of 2.5 amps. That's a limit of 1.67 amps and, to ensure that this isn't exceeded when driving 12 volts onto a gate, a series resistance of 7.2 Ω is needed.

> *How is the current controlled? From what I read about the gate
> resistor \$R_G\$, it only helps in suppressing transients and has no impact
> on drive current. Please correct me if I am wrong here*

\$R_G\$ (calculated as 7.2 Ω from above) limits the output current. If you are only driving 10 volts then 6 Ω would be enough. If driving 15 volts then \$R_G\$ would need to be 9 Ω.

Answer (score 0):

FETs are voltage controlled switches and heat dissipation is the limiting factor switching capacitive gate loads.

The 1st stage can drive 2A @ 12V into the 2nd stage which has a gate charge Qg=6.7nC = CV.

The 1st stage has a low voltage output limit but a lower RdsOn not stated.  The 2nd stage has a very high Vds rating of 650V but also a high RdsOn of 2.1 Ohms.

The power dissipation and heatsink requirements for the 2nd stage are much higher depending on the duration of the pulse. 1st is 500 mW MAX while the 2nd is 10Wdc @ 11 V and then increases with smaller pulse widths.

One can calculate the risetime of the gate pulse from 1st RdsOn estimate and Q=CV of the power gate then add swell time depending on reactance of stored energy in the Power driver and load. (TBD)